# SwiftUI: Cannot convert value of type 'Float' to expected argument type '()'

Tags: swift, swiftui

I'm trying to create rows of Textfields and then store the user's input to a dictionary.

```
@Binding var numPeople: Int
@State var dict: [String : Float] = [:]
@State var name: String = ""
@State var amount: Float = 0.00
.
.
.
ForEach(1...numPeople, id:\.self) { stack in
    HStack {
         TextField("Name", text: $name)
             .padding()
                        
         Text("Amount in $:")
                        
         TextField("", value: $amount, formatter: NumberFormatter())
             .keyboardType(.numberPad)
             .onReceive(Just(amount)) { // I do have Combine imported
                 dict[name] = amount
             }
             .padding()
     }
}
```

But it seems to not work, and I can't figure out why (I'm pretty new to this language). I even checked for an empty `VStack`, `HStack`, etc. All I have is `Cannot convert value of type 'Float' to expected argument type '()'.`

Thank you!

Comment: use this: `.onReceive(Just(amount)) { _ in .....}`

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.